# why not pthread_join() after mq_notify() create a thread which is joinable?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, unix, ipc

I'm learning *THE LINUX PROGRAMING INTERFACE* this book and get confused here.
I invoke the pthread_attr_getdetachstate() and find that thread created by mq_notify() it's JOINABLE, but how to pthread_join() this zoomble(after it terminated) thread?
I saw the man page, but he doesn't use join.

Comment: Some example code would help a lot to clarify what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

I just looked at the `glibc` source code for `mq_notify`.

`mq_notify` starts a *single* control thread with `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED`. Therefore, it is *not* joinable.

The `pthread_t` value that gets set by the call from `mq_notify` to `pthread_create` is *not* available to you. So, whatever value you're using in your `pthread_attr_getdetachstate` call has *no* relationship to the `mq_notify` call.

This control thread created by `mq_notify` may create other threads. But, they also run detached [using `pthread_detach(pthread_self())`].

---

**UPDATE:**

> I wonder whether the OP is talking about using `SIGEV_THREAD` to receive message notifications. It makes some sense that they would want to know about how to manage the thread in which their specified function is called. – John Bollinger

In the `glibc` *wrapper* function `mq_notify` ...

The *first* time `mq_notify` is called, it creates a netlink socket for communication and a *single* control thread.

In the `sigevent` struct [from caller], if `sigev_notify` *is* `SIGEV_THREAD`, the struct can have a [non-null] `pthread_attr_t *` value in `sigev_notify_attributes`. These attributes are copied and passed off to the actual `mq_notify` *syscall* via an internal `struct`

This is because although the syscall *could* create a thread [via an internal `clone` call], it could *not* do this from a signal handler and all the things that `pthread_*` functions do to (e.g.) set up `pthread_t` could *not* be done by the kernel.

So, after that, the [internal] `struct` is [ultimately] sent to the control thread [from the kernel] via a message on the netlink socket. The thread function for the control thread is [in the code below]: `helper_function`

The control thread will set the attributes from that message/struct into the  `pthread_create` call it issues to start a [per-message] notification thread.

But ... The start routine specified in the `pthread_create` is *not* caller's notification/thread function. It is another *wrapper* function (e.g. `notification_function`) that calls `pthread_detach` as I mentioned above. It *then* calls user's start function.

I could be misreading the code, but, AFAICT, by the time the user's callback function has been invoked, it is in a separate thread that has already been detached.

So, again, the thread is *not* joinable. Whether the `pthread_detach` call updates the attributes of the per-message thread so that the caller can do: `pthread_attribute_getdetachstate(pthread_self(),...)` and get this is a bit of a moot point. We *know* it's detached.

So, user/caller's thread function *can't* `pthread_join` itself. And, caller's original thread can no longer manage the notification thread [because, again, it's detached], there really isn't anything to do [or anything that can be done].

---

Here's an excerpt from `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mq_notify.c`:

```
/* The function used for the notification.  */
static void *
notification_function(void *arg)
{
    /* Copy the function and parameter so that the parent thread can go on with its life.  */
    volatile union notify_data *data = (volatile union notify_data *) arg;
    void (*fct) (union sigval) = data->fct;
    union sigval param = data->param;

    /* Let the parent go.  */
    (void) __pthread_barrier_wait(&notify_barrier);

    /* Make the thread detached.  */
    (void) pthread_detach(pthread_self());

    /* The parent thread has all signals blocked.  This is probably a bit surprising for this thread.  So we unblock all of them.  */
    (void) change_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, NULL);

    /* Now run the user code.  */
    fct(param);

    /* And we are done.  */
    return NULL;
}

/* Helper thread.  */
static void *
helper_thread(void *arg)
{
    while (1) {
        union notify_data data;

        ssize_t n = __recv(netlink_socket, &data, sizeof(data),
            MSG_NOSIGNAL | MSG_WAITALL);

        if (n < NOTIFY_COOKIE_LEN)
            continue;

        if (data.raw[NOTIFY_COOKIE_LEN - 1] == NOTIFY_WOKENUP) {
            /* Just create the thread as instructed.  There is no way to report a problem with creating a thread.  */
            pthread_t th;

            if (__builtin_expect(pthread_create(&th, data.attr, notification_function, &data)
                    == 0, 0))
                /* Since we passed a pointer to DATA to the new thread we have to wait until it is done with it.  */
                (void) __pthread_barrier_wait(&notify_barrier);
        }
        else if (data.raw[NOTIFY_COOKIE_LEN - 1] == NOTIFY_REMOVED)
            /* The only state we keep is the copy of the thread attributes.  */
            free(data.attr);
    }
    return NULL;
}

static void
reset_once(void)
{
    once = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
}

static void
init_mq_netlink(void)
{
    /* This code might be called a second time after fork().  The file descriptor is inherited from the parent.  */
    if (netlink_socket == -1) {
        /* Just a normal netlink socket, not bound.  */
        netlink_socket = __socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW | SOCK_CLOEXEC, 0);
        /* No need to do more if we have no socket.  */
        if (netlink_socket == -1)
            return;
    }

    int err = 1;

    /* Initialize the barrier.  */
    if (__builtin_expect(__pthread_barrier_init(&notify_barrier, NULL, 2) == 0, 0)) {
        /* Create the helper thread.  */
        pthread_attr_t attr;

        (void) pthread_attr_init(&attr);
        (void) pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
        /* We do not need much stack space, the bare minimum will be enough.  */
        (void) pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, __pthread_get_minstack(&attr));

        /* Temporarily block all signals so that the newly created thread inherits the mask.  */
        sigset_t oss;
        int have_no_oss = change_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &oss);

        pthread_t th;

        err = pthread_create(&th, &attr, helper_thread, NULL);

        /* Reset the signal mask.  */
        if (!have_no_oss)
            pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oss, NULL);

        (void) pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

        if (err == 0) {
            static int added_atfork;

            if (added_atfork == 0 && pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, reset_once) != 0) {
                /* The child thread will call recv() which is a cancellation point.  */
                (void) pthread_cancel(th);
                err = 1;
            }
            else
                added_atfork = 1;
        }
    }

    if (err != 0) {
        __close_nocancel_nostatus(netlink_socket);
        netlink_socket = -1;
    }
}

/* Register notification upon message arrival to an empty message queue
   MQDES.  */
int
mq_notify(mqd_t mqdes, const struct sigevent *notification)
{
    /* Make sure the type is correctly defined.  */
    assert(sizeof(union notify_data) == NOTIFY_COOKIE_LEN);

    /* Special treatment needed for SIGEV_THREAD.  */
    if (notification == NULL || notification->sigev_notify != SIGEV_THREAD)
        return INLINE_SYSCALL(mq_notify, 2, mqdes, notification);

    /* The kernel cannot directly start threads.  This will have to be done at userlevel.  Since we cannot start threads from signal handlers we have to create a dedicated thread which waits for notifications for arriving messages and creates threads in response.  */

    /* Initialize only once.  */
    pthread_once(&once, init_mq_netlink);

    /* If we cannot create the netlink socket we cannot provide SIGEV_THREAD support.  */
    if (__glibc_unlikely(netlink_socket == -1)) {
        __set_errno(ENOSYS);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Create the cookie.  It will hold almost all the state.  */
    union notify_data data;

    memset(&data, '\0', sizeof(data));
    data.fct = notification->sigev_notify_function;
    data.param = notification->sigev_value;

    if (notification->sigev_notify_attributes != NULL) {
        /* The thread attribute has to be allocated separately.  */
        data.attr = (pthread_attr_t *) malloc(sizeof(pthread_attr_t));
        if (data.attr == NULL)
            return -1;

        memcpy(data.attr, notification->sigev_notify_attributes, sizeof(pthread_attr_t));
    }

    /* Construct the new request.  */
    struct sigevent se;

    se.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    se.sigev_signo = netlink_socket;
    se.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &data;

    /* Tell the kernel.  */
    int retval = INLINE_SYSCALL(mq_notify, 2, mqdes, &se);

    /* If it failed, free the allocated memory.  */
    if (__glibc_unlikely(retval != 0))
        free(data.attr);

    return retval;
}
```

Comment: I wonder whether the OP is talking about using `SIGEV_THREAD` to receive message notifications.  It makes some sense that they would want to know about how to manage the thread in which their specified function is called.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've dug a little deeper into the code and addressed this in the UPDATE section of my answer.